# Назначение своих методов для встроенных обьектов js

Tags: javascript

На собеседовании в одну фирму мне попался следующий вопрос: сделайте свой метод для массиовов, который будет возвращать сумму членов массива и кот будет работать следующим образом: [1,2,3].sum();
Попытался назначить обьекту Array мои метод: Array.sum = function() {...}, но firebug выдает ошибку, что sum не функция, как можно решить эту проблему? И если не затруднит, сможет ли кто нибудь дать ссылку на статью о создании собственных методов для массивов в js.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Попробуйте через `Array.prototype.sum`

Comment: А кроме как через prototype этот не возможно реализовать? Нашел примеры его использования, все подходит, но мне все таки кажется, что требовалось другое решение.

Comment: prototype - это лучшее решение

Все методы массивов типа push, pop и т.д.

И это справедливо не только для массивов

Comment: ок, спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Мда. Человек ответил правильно, и хоть бы кто-то + поставил ...


что за народ жадный пошел...